# What SQL would I need to use to list all the stored procedures on an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

What SQL would I need to use to list all the stored procedures on an Oracle database?

If possible I'd like two queries:

1. list all stored procedures by name
2. list the code of a stored procedure, given a name

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `DBA_OBJECTS` view will list the procedures (as well as almost any other object):

```
SELECT owner, object_name
FROM dba_objects 
WHERE object_type = 'PROCEDURE'
```

The `DBA_SOURCE` view will list the lines of source code for a procedure in question:

```
SELECT line, text
FROM dba_source
WHERE owner = ?
  AND name = ?
  AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
ORDER BY line
```

**Note:** Depending on your privileges, you may not be able to query the `DBA_OBJECTS` and `DBA_SOURCE` views. In this case, you can use `ALL_OBJECTS` and `ALL_SOURCE` instead. The `DBA_` views contain **all** objects in the database, whereas the `ALL_` views contain only those objects that you may access.

Comment: You want to do object_type in ('PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION', 'PACKAGE') to get all the possible source code.

Comment: Sorry, total Oracle noob here. I can't seem to see that view/table. Does that mean I'm logged in as the wrong user?

Comment: You may not have the privileges necessary to query those views. You can try ALL_OBJECTS and ALL_SOURCE instead.

Comment: Worked with ALL_*, want to update the answer to have that and I'll accept it?

Comment: I kept the DBA_ views in the example, but I added a note explaining the ALL_ views. The DBA_ views are still preferable if you have access to them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler SQL `SELECT * FROM User_Procedures;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the calls to introspect stored procedures (parameters, etc), you can pull it out of this open source package:

http://code.google.com/p/orapig

OraPIG is the Oracle Python Interface Generator.  It introspects oracle packages and generates python wrappers for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think enumerating from DBA_OBJECTS may have missed out a lot of procedures:
(I am on Oracle 12c, login as SYS)

```
select count(*) from dba_objects where object_type = 'PROCEDURE';
       202
```

It really looked impossible that the entire ORACLE database can have only 202 procedures.

And querying from DBA_PROCEDURES:

```
select owner||'-'||object_name || '-'||procedure_name from
dba_procedures WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME IS NOT NULL;

26539 rows selected.
```

Now focusing on SYS schema, which comes default for every database (not unique to mine):

Querying for ANONYMOUS stored procedures (http://www.praetoriate.com/t_high_perform_calling_procedures.htm) belonging to SYS:

```
select owner||'-'||object_name || '-'||procedure_name from dba_procedures WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME IS NULL and owner = 'SYS';
994 rows selected.
```

And SYS's non-anonymous stored procedures have 15K:

```
select owner||'-'||object_name || '-'||procedure_name from dba_procedures WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME IS NOT NULL and owner = 'SYS';
15408 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all stored procedures in the database you're connected to, simply execute this:

`select object_name from user_procedures;`

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_PROCEDURES;
```